# Reading from s3 bucket with thousands of s3 objects

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, inputstream

I have one s3 bucket with has 12,000 s3 objects. I want to read these s3 objects,in batches (say 50). I have set the number of max connections to 1000 (but we have 12,000 and its generally not a good practice to open these many connections at once when ultimately I am going to read only few at a time) I have multithreaded java code, which reads from these s3 objects, each s3 object is assigned to one thread. Here is the problem
1. I want to read s3 objects in batches, say 50 at a time, but since we are reading only 50 objects from bucket and assigning S3ObjectInputStream to one thread, I am getting connection reset error for all other input streams have been waiting to actually start reading from s3 object

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

What is the best way to approach this kind of problem.

I have increased max number of connections to 1000, though I have 12k, how can i automate this, so that I dont have to split s3 bucket to 1000 objects at my end.

Comment: You need yo share your code.

Comment: Its not about code. I am asking for approach on dealing with thousands of s3 objects in batches.

Comment: What is your actual end-goal that you are trying to achieve? There might be a better way to achieve it. For example, what type of files are they (CSV? JSON? Compressed?) and what processing is being performed on them? It could be a suitable use-case for Amazon Athena, but we'd need more details to be sure.

Comment: @Mohini - I think it is about your code(!).  I suspect the resets are the S3 server's reaction to you doing something wrong on your side; e.g. having too many simultaneous connections, or opening them and then not reading from them soon enough.  Either way, your descriptions are not clear enough for us to be sure what you are actually doing.  If we don't know, we cannot say what the cause is, and what you could do to fix it.  The code will *show* us what you are doing.

Comment: @StephenC yes, actually i was opening all connections at once. Figured that out and fixed it. Btw thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the problem is that you are trying to use S3 Batch to do something it doesn't support.  The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/batch-ops-basics.html) says:

> To create a job, you give Amazon S3 batch operations a list of objects and specify the action to perform on those objects. Amazon S3 batch operations support the following operations:
>
> - PUT copy object
> - PUT object tagging
> - PUT object ACL
> - Initiate Glacier restore
> - Invoke an AWS Lambda function

Object GET is not in that list.

(But if you showed us a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we could understand what you are really doing!)